# ternary operator and interpolation

Tags: css, stylus

This question is no longer valid!

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary operator and interpolation here:

```
useShortNames = true
selector = useShortNames ? '[class*="mobile-",class*="m-"]' : '[class*="mobile-"]'

{selector}
  float: left
  padding-right: 20px
```